# Overlap BackgroundImage With Overlay in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I wanted to have a background overlay on my background image. I wanted to achieve something on this below:

[image: CHECK THIS IMAGE]

Pls check my codesanbox also

[Click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-4gsib?file=/demo.js:1170-1411)

```
 image: {
    backgroundImage:
      "linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 0, 150, 0.3), #06a303), url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature/2)",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundPosition: "center"
  },
```

Comment: So I've taken a look at your sandbox and I see an a color gradient overlaying an image. What is the issue? Please be specific.

Comment: @DrewReese. I wanted it to cover the whole image. and put an opacity because I'll be putting a text on it. So the text needs to be seen clearly. I hope you got what i mean. Thank you

Comment: I guess I don't understand then. In your sandbox the overlay and image occupy the same space, so the image is covered. Are you trying to get the "login form" to look like a modal as it appears to be in the linked image above?

Comment: Hi. I've edited my codesandbox. I put a `<Grid item xs={false} sm={4} md={7} className={classes.image}>
          <h1>Text Here...</h1>
        </Grid>`. I think a black background color overlay with an opacity would be good. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, that is typically how the overlay would work. Are you saying you *don't* want the red(ish)-green gradient overlay? Sorry, I still don't understand if you are saying what you currently have isn't working, of if it is or isn't what you are going for, or something else altogether.

Comment: @Drew Reese. i dont like how my gradient looks.i want an overlay black background with an opacity. you can fork my codesandbox so i can see how it looks. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a sold gradient, black @ about 50-60% opacity, with your background image under it. White text and some padding help the text pop.

```
backgroundImage:
  "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature/2)",
```

[image]

Code

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  ...
  image: {
    backgroundImage:
      "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature/2)",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundPosition: "center",
    color: "white",
    padding: "1rem"
  },
  ...
}));
```

[image: Edit overlap-backgroundimage-with-overlay-in-react]

Comment: Great Job Drew. Thank you